# Spans aren't hyperlinking inside anchor

Tags: html, css

Here's the [**entire** code](http://codebin.org/view/f4296ef9).

Here's the applicable code:

```
<a href='http://app.bithumor.co/report_post?id=568'><span class='report_icon'></span></a>
```

With CSS:

```
<style>
.report_icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 17px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: url(http://s10.postimg.org/7e5s3kasl/more_info.png);
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 13px;
}
</style>
```

Clicking on the `span` tag is not navigating me to the `href`.

If you would like to the code love, then you can view it here: http://test.bithumor.co/test9.php, the `span`s that are within anchors are the usernames and the three dots "**...**"

Comment: your live code gives a 404 page

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @dippas i just fixed the link

Comment: Can't reproduce: the links work properly.

Answer (score 2):

just add this to your CSS

```
.entire_post a {
  display:block
}
```

you can always create a class to that first `a`  and with that `display:block` will affect just the first `a` and not other `a` siblings.

why?

because `a` (and `span` as well) is an `inline` element.

**NOTE;** In your code (live demo)  you have, `<center>` and `<font>` which are outdated among other errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the anchor tag, add a class to it or do something like this. I would recommend a class though.

```
.entire_post > div a:last-child {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

You also have an issue where your `.post_bar` div contains a `<br>` which expands the height of the `.post_bar` and blocks the anchor tag. Remove the `<br>`-tag.

Might be worth knowing that using `<br>` for layout is considered bad practice, so try to use only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your site, there are many more issues than **just** these links not functioning. That being said, if you look closely at your site, you can see that just the first post has these issues and every other post's links are working. The reason for this is that the `div` with the `post_bar` class is not closed properly because it is interrupted by a `br`. If you close this tag properly (and maybe get rid of those `br`s completely, the links will work properly.

Some other notes for your site:

- remember to use `html`, `head`, and `body` tags.
- the `post_bar` `div` should have its attribute `top` set to 0px to keep it at the top of the screen since its position is fixed.
- the first `entire_post` `div` should have a `margin-top` of 75px to keep it under the `post_bar` instead of using `br`s.